# Keyboard map changes with TTY

Tags: centos, console, keyboard-layout

I'm Belgian, and so the keyboard layout on my CentOS 7 is `be-latin1`.

I've set it up with `# loadkeys be-latin1`. Everything up to here is fine, my chars are all corrects.

The thing is, when I switch to another TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd>), the keyboard layout is qwerty...

How can I set this keyboard layout to `be-latin1` too ?
Is it possible to do this *everywhere* in the PC ?

I tried editing the file `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard`, but it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your vconsole.conf

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/vconsole.conf
**KEYMAP="be-latin1"**
FONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
[root@localhost ~]#

Resource : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_console

Answer (score 1):

I think on CentOS it is `system-config-keyboard` (although I don't believe this will affect grub).

Comment: It's already installed, and the problem remains. PS : The grub part was irrelevant on the machine I work on...

Comment: Yes, `system-config-keyboard` can add languages/layouts into login screen for you to choose(some extra clicks, atop of the login screen), apart from `en(US)` layout, in case the new layouts fails. Quite useful.